# UWP Verify user account name and password

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

**1)** I'm having a problem finding a reference for verifying password in Win10IoTCore(for gateway devices).

From what I search, most are giving reference with description of verifying "email" as username/for Windows Phone xx/webserver. I just want to verify password in current local devices only which likely "Logon Screen" in normal windows.

What I have so far is getting the user account name only:-

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var hostNames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
    var hostName = hostNames.FirstOrDefault(name => name.Type == HostNameType.DomainName)?.DisplayName ?? "???";
    tb_accname.Text = hostName.ToString();
}
```

**2)** What I want to ask here too; to find what I want to search for UWP code for Windows, how do I type for search? Currently I'm using *"C# UWP xxxmyquestionherexxxxx"* but the result appear with description related for phone app(mostly).

Currently the development is right on my notebook so it should verify with my windows password right?

[image: IoT Login Screen[![][1]]

**EXPLORED WEBLINK AND TEST:-**

[Active Directory](http://abundantcode.com/how-to-validate-a-user-in-active-directory-using-c/)
| [Credential Locker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker)